# Bash: Get pid of a process using a different user

Tags: linux, bash, app-id

I have a script in bash to start a java program and I want to get the pid of the program after it executes. The pid will be saved in a text file.

Right now I have something like this:

```
if [ "$USER" == "root" ]
then
    su $APP_USER -c "nohup java $JAVA_OPTS  >> $LOG_OUT 2>> $LOG_ERR &"
    su $APP_USER -c "echo $! > $PID_PATH/$CAT.pid"
else
    nohup java $JAVA_OPTS >> $LOG_OUT 2>> $LOG_ERR &
    echo $! > "$PID_PATH/$CAT.pid"
fi
```

I also tried like this but it doesn't work neither.

```
if [ "$USER" == "root" ]
then
    su $APP_USER -c "(nohup java $JAVA_OPTS  >> $LOG_OUT 2>> $LOG_ERR &); (echo $! > $PID_PATH/$CAT.pid)"
else
    nohup java $JAVA_OPTS >> $LOG_OUT 2>> $LOG_ERR &
    echo $! > "$PID_PATH/$CAT.pid"
fi
```

when I run as my APP_USER all works great, when I run as root my java program starts but the pid file is created empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
su $APP_USER -c "nohup java $JAVA_OPTS  >> $LOG_OUT 2>> $LOG_ERR & echo \$! > $PID_PATH/$CAT.pid"
```

`\` behind `$!` prevents expansion of the variable, before passing to the su command.

Comment: This command work, but the file is written empty.
I don't get the pid.

Comment: It work !! :D
You were rigth, `echo` was giving an empty string. Thats why the pid file was empty.

Comment: Tanks for the feed back. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each `su` command is a separate invocation of the user, so `$!` won't store your last PID since there isn't one.

What you have to do is save your PID in the same invocation as the first `su`. The easiest way to do this is to put quotation marks around both commands and separate them by a semicolon

```
su $APP_USER -c "nohup java $JAVA_OPTS  >> $LOG_OUT 2>> $LOG_ERR &; "echo $! > $PID_PATH/$CAT.pid"
```

Now `su` will invoke both commands in the same environment.

Comment: It makes sense, I try your command it gives a sintax error, but it can be fixed using ().
    `su $APP_USER -c "(nohup java $JAVA_OPTS  >> $LOG_OUT 2>> $LOG_ERR &); (echo $! > $PID_PATH/$CAT.pid)"`

but still I get an empty file with no pid.

Comment: Using `(...)` executes the command in a sub-shell. Since you put `echo $!` in a separate sub-shell, it won't have the PID of the previous command. Don't use `(...)` or put both sets of commands in the same `(...)`. You can also try curly braces like `{...}`. This executes your command in the same shell (but you must terminate with `;`)

Comment: I was having a issue with the `&;` at the end of the first statment.  I didn't need the `;`.
The `(...)` seem to solve it... but I need to escape the `$!` -> `\$!`.
it work like this:
`su $APP_USER -c "nohup java $JAVA_OPTS >> $LOG_OUT 2>> $LOG_ERR & echo \$! > $PID_PATH/$CAT.pid"`
Tanks for your feedback. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your system provides `start-stop-daemon` it may be easier to use that instead of creating crazy wrappers. By default you get the user changing (`--user`) and nohup behaviour (`--background`). Additionally you can use `--make-pidfile` that will do the right thing - whether you switch the user or not.

Comment: Hello, this seem interesting, but I think my SO doesn't support that.
Maybe a need to install something new. I am new in bash scripting, this has something to do with how `su -c "command"` work. I will do some more research. Tanks for your feedback.