# Why this bash script can't get the pid of the background process by $!

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script like that:

```
su lingcat -c PHPRC\=\/home\/lingcat\/etc\/php5\ 
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN\=4\ \/usr\/bin\/php\-loop\.pl\ \/usr\/bin\/php5\-cgi\ \-b\ 
127\.0\.0\.1\:9006\ \>\>\/home\/lingcat\/logs\/php\.log\ 2\>\&1\ \<\/dev\/null\ \&\ 
echo\ \$\!\ \>\/var\/php\-nginx\/135488849520817\.php\.pid
```

This is working. But there is too many `\` in the script, they make the code unreadable. So, I wrote a new shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
'start')
        su biergaizi -c "PHPRC=/home/biergaizi/etc/php5 PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=2 
/usr/bin/php-loop.pl /usr/bin/php-cgi -b /var/run/virtualhost/php5-fpm-biergaizi.test.sock >>/home/biergaizi/logs/php.log 2>&1 </dev/null & 
echo $! > /var/php-nginx/biergaizi.test.php.pid"
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
'stop')
        su biergaizi -c "kill `cat /var/php-nginx/biergaizi.test.php.pid` ; sleep 1"
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
'restart')
        $0 stop ; $0 start
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
*)
        echo "Usage: $0 { start | stop }"
        RETVAL=1
        ;;
esac
exit
```

But `/var/php-nginx/biergaizi.test.php.pid` is empty.

What's wrong?

Comment: Woah! Since when do you need to escape a forward-slash? Have you heard of quotes? You might find "jobs -p %1" more helpful in bash than just "$!" for getting the pid of background processes in general.

Comment: This question is similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542417/bash-get-pid-of-a-process-using-a-diferent-user/16542582#16542582

Comment: @Nicholas Wilson I never escape a forward-slash, but the auto-script-generator does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .pid file is empty, because `$!` gets substituted by the shell executing your script, instead of the shell executing the commands you pass through `su`. And as there is no recently started background command in your script, it substitutes an empty string. So, shell started by `su` executes simply `echo > /var/php-nginx/biergaizi.test.php.pid`.

To prevent that, quote your command passed to `su` using single quotes, instead of double quotes. It is better to do that to the "stop" command as well. Like this:

```
su biergaizi -c 'PHPRC=/home/biergaizi/etc/php5 PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=2 
                 /usr/bin/php-loop.pl /usr/bin/php-cgi -b /var/run/virtualhost/php5-fpm-biergaizi.test.sock >>/home/biergaizi/logs/php.log 2>&1 </dev/null & 
                 echo $! > /var/php-nginx/biergaizi.test.php.pid'
```

And this:

```
su biergaizi -c 'kill `cat /var/php-nginx/biergaizi.test.php.pid` ; sleep 1'
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html for details.

Comment: Thanks. I know `$!` is the source of the problem. I tried to escape it by `\$\!` but without success (I know why, now) Using single quotes is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Escape `$` from `$!`, before passing to `su -c`.